# Select and group MySql table

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help to count and group some MySql table records according of a range of dates given.
The table strcutre is this:

[image]

In advance, thank you for your help

Comment: I need a little help understanding your question.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good. I have a MySql table (structure on top), and I need to do a query, so I can get , group by date, and flight the totals of tickets ordered by date. Each record is a ticket, hope you understand .

Comment: So, tell me in plain English, what you are trying to count

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shoud give you the result that you need:

```
SELECT
  d1.dt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t1.recid) AS departures,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.recid) AS returns,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t1.recid) + COUNT(DISTINCT t2.recid) AS total
FROM (SELECT departure_date AS dt FROM yourtable
      UNION SELECT return_date FROM yourtable) d1
  LEFT JOIN yourtable t1 ON d1.dt = t1.departure_date
  LEFT JOIN yourtable t2 ON d1.dt = t2.return_date
GROUP BY
  d1.dt
```

The first subquery will return all dates, not duplicated, present in your table (departures and returns).

I'm then trying to join each date to a departure date, using a LEFT JOIN. I'm then counting the DISTINCT t1.recid that make the join succeed..

I'm then trying to join each date to a return date, using LEFT JOIN. Total is the sum of both counts.

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b59e/4).

Comment: Hey, man, thank you very much, it works for me !! how incredible fast you post the explanation and put the example, you rocks !!!